# GridView SelectedRowStyle not applied to row selected in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On pageIndexChanged, I set the first row in the grid to be selected, as follows:

```
//I'd love to get rid of this, but the SelectedDataKey is empty otherwise
Grid.DataBind();   

Grid.SelectedIndex = 0;

Grid.Rows[0].RowState = DataControlRowState.Selected;
```

The row is selected, but the SelectedRowStyle is not applied. Even if I reset it, like so

```
Grid.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass = "selected";
```

Any ideas why the style isn't applied? Thanks!

Comment: plz set in grid databound event, I have tested....

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it's an EntityFramework issue. Thanks for trying. No doubt with straightforward ADO.NET situation, you'd be correct.

Comment: You're going to have to check the actual rendered page, and see if the style is in there.

Comment: Good point. I did that, and it is not. It should show <tr class="selected"> on the row output. Of course I could manipulate this in some kludgy way, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1):

try to set this in the grid DataBound event

Grid.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass = "selected";